# How does Assert.assertEquals(object 1, object2) compare two Objects?

Tags: java, junit

How does Assert.assertEquals(Object1, Object2) compare both objects ?

In java, when you compare object1 and object2 using Object1.equals(object2), they are not equal even though the content of the object is same.

Where as if you compare String1.equals(String2) this will show both string as same even though they are different objects.

```
String a = "hi there";
String b = "hi there";
a.equals(b) returns true


JSONObject j1 = (new JSONObject()).put("a","hi there");
JSONObject j2 = (new JSONObject()).put("a","hi there");
j1.equals(j2) does not return true;
```

Q) Why are objects not converted to binary stream and then not compared to check if they are same ?

q) Assert.assertEquals(j1,j2): assertion fails. why ?

Comment: just a note `a` and `b` in your code are **not** "different objects", they reference the same instance of string: `a == b` will result in `true`

Comment: `object1.equals(object2)` works fine if the type overrides `equals`. It looks like `JSONObject` doesn't, and it's as simple as that.

Comment: why not convert to binary? it is the developer that *should* decide when 2 objects are equal or not. why `assertEquals` fails? because the objects are not `equal` (according their implementation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up different ideas.

One concept is known as *identity*: are two references pointing to the same object, that is, the same chunk of memory? This is what `==` tests, as in `x == y` where x and y are reference variables (pointers) rather than primitives.

The `.equals` method on the `Object` class has a different intention. That method asks if the *meaning* of two objects is the same. The method judges if the content of two objects are significantly the same. In some cases “significantly” means *exactly* the same for every value of every field.  What that means exactly is up to the particular subclass inheriting from `Object`. Whoever writes the implementation of `equals` gets to decide on what should be compared between the two objects.

As for comparing binary streams, first of all, objects don’t have a binary stream. Furthermore, even two pieces of text can have the same meaning yet vary in their bits – just look up [Unicode Normalization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence). Or even the simpler case where in some situations two pieces of text might be considered equivalent if we choose to ignore uppercase versus lowercase, ex: `Dog` and `dog` and `DOG` might all three be considered that same while each carries different octets.

Context is everything.

> In java, when you compare object1 and object2 using Object1.equals(object2), they are not equal even though the content of the object is same.

Your statement simply cannot be made about all classes. You must look to each class’ implementation of `equals`. Class `Foo` might compare every last piece of state in the object, while class `Bar` might choose to compare only a single `id` field of type [`UUID`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) while ignoring the value in all the rest of its fields.

> Assert.assertEquals(j1,j2): assertion fails. why ?

I do not know. I’d have to look up the Javadoc for the implementation of the `Object::equals` method override for the particular class in question (`JSONObject` in your case).

The point is that *you* must look up the `equals` method documentation for each comparison you make.

Likewise, be sure to write clear documentation for every `equals` method override you implement.

Answer (score 3):

`Assert.assertEquals` uses `Object::equals` underneath to compare objects. So `Object::equals` method has to be overriden for the given class, if the comparing behaviour, for instances of this class, should be changed. You are using [`org.json.JSONObject`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.json/json/20180813) and this implementation does not override `equals` method from `Object` class. `Object::equals` method has following implementation :

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
     return (this == obj);
}
```

so it basically checks if two references (`this` and `obj` **point to the same object**). That is why your second assertion fails.

Comment: "Thise method should be overriden" it's not clear which method you are saying should be overridden.